# Oracle SQL Database creating a clob with size greater than 4000

Tags: sql, database, oracle, clob

I'm trying to alter table and add a new column as a clob, but I'm only allowed to set the size to 4,000. The syntax I'm using is:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
add column_name CLOB(100000)
```

The error I'm getting is:

> ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option

If I put:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
add column_name CLOB
```

This allows me to create a column of default size 4,000.

Comment: You cannot specify a size for CLOB. The limit for LOB is several GB (or even TB on current releases).

Comment: The issue is not likely to be the CLOB column, it's more likely to be how you are trying to add the data into the column. How are you trying to populate the column?

Comment: @Boneist through a php script, but all I'm trying to do right now is add a column, not populate it

Comment: @Daoud where are you getting the "default size of 4000" from? If it's from dba/all/user_tab_columns, then ignore it. I would assume that the data_length for LOB columns refers to the maximum amount of data that can be stored inline (i.e. without having to store the CLOB in memory outside of the table and then adding a pointer to the memory area in the table row). See [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28393/adlob_tables.htm#sthref200) for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is telling you `invalid ALTER TABLE option` because it is an invalid option - you can't specify the size of the clob.

Comment: how do i surpass the 4,000 byte limit, because varchar2 also allows 4,000

Comment: which version of oracle db are you using?

Comment: 11.1, it should be oracle 11c

Comment: As Boneist pointed out then it's unlikely to be anything to do with the clob size.  In Oracle 10 and above the maximum clob size is (4 GB - 1) * DB_BLOCK_SIZE  (see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/limits001.htm#i287903), so if the tablespace in your database are of standard blocksize (8k) then CLOB has max length of 4GB * 8000 = 32TB.

Comment: do you know why it's always setting the size to 4,000 bytes? could it be a default size set somewhere by a database administrator?

Comment: Have you tried creating a clob bigger than the max size?  I would try that first before getting caught up in the size setting.